# How to stop a 302 redirect to my domain?

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-302

A spamming site is doing a 302 redirect (temporary redirect) to my site. In google search results if you click on *spamingsite.com* you are redirected to *mysite.com*. Is there a way to know that the request is coming from a 302 redirect and block it at the server?

PS: I'm using Nginx.

Answer (score 3):

Your request will have an http_referrer, you can use that header to add an if condition in your nginx config, or you can use the [valid referrer module explained here](http://wiki.nginx.org/Referrer_Spam_Blocking)

```
location / {
  valid_referers none blocked spamsite.com;

  if ($invalid_referer) {
    return   403;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does't that mean spamsite.com is one of the valid refrers?

Comment: Personally I never tried this directive, but what the wiki says is that those referrers are the ones that are going to be blocked, check the link I have in the answer.

Comment: I'm getting 403 on clicking any link on _mysite.com_ after adding this. If I add _mysite.com_ to the list of valid referers then there is no problem.

Comment: ok i think im starting to understand this, try replacing `none` with `yoursite.com`, or just `*`